# Remote access via ssh with password

Tags: ssh, remote-access

During my experiments with VPS (11.10 x86) I meet some problem with remote access to my machine.

After installing the system, I'm able to login via Putty from Windows machine (default account with root privileges) with password.

In next step I've created new user:

```
adduser gsa
```

After that I've tried to login via ssh:

```
ssh gsa@localhost
```

and everything works correctly (so password is correct).

In situation when I'm trying to access my machine as `gsa` user (from Putty@Windows) I receive `Access denied`.

Some extra info:

```
ssh -vv gsa@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
.
.
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
gsa@80.82.23.124's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I have placed:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowUsers gsa
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a shell set for the gsa user?

You should not need to have the AllowedUsers line in there, by default anyone allowed to login should be able to ssh  in as well (well, aside from root).

On the ssh server what does 'getent passwd gsa' return?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Problem was related with shell configuration. Now everything works correctly.